# Collision-free one-wayish function mapping 32 bit to 32 bit

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, one-way-function

As simple as it may sound, I was unable to find a collsion free one-way(ish) function which takes 32 bits of input and produces 32 bits of output. I apologize if I just didn't knew the right keywords to find the function.

Of course, $2^{32}$ is within a range which can be easily bruteforced within a couple of seconds on modern mid to high end retail PC's but the goal is to not let attackers find the input in a way faster than bruteforce.

Also the function should be proven to be collision free, which can be achieved by bruteforcing each $2^{32}$ input. I'm willing to take that task upon me if someone hasn't got the time to do so (or just doesn't want to).

EDIT: I forgot to mention the attack scenario and already discarded ideas:

The function will run in a white-box enviroment so I'd rather not use functions relying on keys to be secure (like Pseudo-Random-Permutations).

I also tried turncating hash functions like SHA-2, Keccak or the underlying hash function of ChaCha. Sadly, all of them have collision when being truncated to 32 bit.

The function will be used to obfuscate if-statements by comparing the outputs of the function.

Comment: Have you tried truncating a common hash function (maybe SHA-256)?

Comment: I tried a couple of hash function, sadly all of them had collisions when being truncated to 32 bit.

Comment: Okay, then how about a stream cipher with a fixed key? Or a [PRP](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/prp.html).

Comment: I've already thought about PRP's, but since it will have to run in a white-box environment and probably will face some competent reverse engineers, I'd rather use a function not relying on keys to be secure.

Comment: Same number of input and output, no collision, then it will be a permutation. Attacker can just build a LookUpTable through bruteforce and then use it to invert any value just through a table lookup.

Comment: @Ruggero Yes, I know, but the attack still shouldn't be able to inverse the function with significantly faster than brute-forcing / building a lookup-table.

Comment: @Ruggero If we use a random member of a large enough family of functions (i.e. the way one-way functions are defined) precomputing a look-up table should be infeasible. This is strictly necessary, otherwise as you correctly note inverting is essentially a single memory access.

Comment: It is not clear to me why a function that relies on a key (which will be fixed in source code) will not work. Are you afraid that the attacker (knowing the key) can be significantly faster than brute force?

Comment: @Maeher No. Input size is $2^{32}$, you just need $2^{32}$ calls to your function to build a look-up table. $2^{32}$ calls to e.g. SHA-512 is very feasible. A whitebox implementation can be used to build such a table and then inverting any output will be trivial. The requirement "the goal is to not let attackers find the input in a way faster than bruteforce" is senseless in my opion. It should be better explained.

Comment: @mikeazo Yes, I'm afraid that an attack knowing the key would be able to invert the typical PRP (or block-cipher) significantly faster since they would be able to use an invertion function for the block-cipher.

Comment: @Ruggero I know that once the lookup tyble is build, you don't need to bruteforce again, but the attacker still has to do all 2^{32} calculations. What I'm trying to prevent is the attacker being able to recover a key for an underlying block-cipher and then being able to invert the function with $O(1)$ komplexity.

Comment: This may be somewhere that [white box crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/386/what-are-the-differences-between-white-box-cryptography-and-code-obfuscation) could be used. Can you explain to us what the application you are targeting is? Maybe there is a different approach besides this 32 bit to 32 bit mapping.

Comment: @mikeazo The function will be used to obfuscate if-statements (by comparing the outputs of the function.

Comment: A full table lookup of this size is only 16GB, this fits easily into RAM on my laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is wanted a permutation of the 32-bit integers that is sizably more difficult to compute in the reverse direction than it is in the forward direction. Obviously, the ratio can't be more than $2^{31}$, since that's the cost of reversing the function by brute force. Also it is useful that the thing is parametrized; otherwise, it could be tabulated, and even reduced to a rainbow table.

---

I propose a construction using the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) in $\Bbb Z_p^*$ and [cycle walking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#FPE_from_cycle_walking).

Let $p$ be a prime with $q=(p-1)/2$ prime and $p\bmod8=7$ (which implies that $2^q\bmod p=1$, and $2$ is a generator of the subgroup of [quadratic residues](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/qr.html) modulo $p$, of prime order $q$). The function $f_p$ defined for integer $x$ by
$$x\mapsto f_p(x)=\min\big((2^x\bmod p),\,p-(2^x\bmod p)\big)$$
is a permutation of the integers in $[1,q]$ which is easy to compute in the forward direction, but requires solving the DLP in $\Bbb Z_p^*$ to reverse. Illustration for $p=47$

```
   x =  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
fp(x)=  2  4  8 16 15 17 13 21  5 10 20  7 14 19  9 18 11 22  3  6 12 23  1
```

This property also holds if we add two parameters $a$ and $b$ with $1\le a<q$ and $0\le b<q$, giving
$$x\mapsto f_{(p,a,b)}(x)=\min\Big(\big({(2^a)}^{x+b}\bmod p\big),\,p-\big({(2^a)}^{x+b}\bmod p\big)\Big)$$

With $p>2^{33}$, the function ${\tilde f}_{(p,a,b)}$ obtained by iterating that $f_{(p,a,b)}$ while the result is larger than $2^{32}$ is a permutation of the integers in $[1,2^{32}]$.

And now $x\mapsto h_{(p,a,b)}(x)={\tilde f}_{(p,a,b)}(x+1)-1$ defines a permutation $h_{(p,a,b)}$ of the 32-bit integers, as desired, which is considerably easier to evaluate in the forward direction than it is to invert.

As an illustration, for $p=\lceil2^{32}\pi\rceil+3062=13493040767$, $a=1$, $b=42$, it is easy to compute $h_{(p,a,b)}(4)=2511267353$ (because $f_{(p,a,b)}(5)=5073155518>2^{32}$, $f_{(p,a,b)}(5073155518)=5723706427>2^{32}$, $f_{(p,a,b)}(5723706427)=2511267354\le2^{32}$). But it is sizably more difficult to solve $h_{(p,a,b)}(x)=2919107273$ for $x$. Try it!

I guesstimate that inversion for one output is several hundreds times harder than direct computation even using sophisticated algorithms to solve the DLP ([index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm) or [NFS](https://is.cuni.cz/webapps/zzp/download/120212103)); thousands times harder with simpler algorithms ([BSGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) or [Pollard's ρ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm)); and hundreds thousands times harder by brute force.

In a white box context, it might be slightly better to have the implementation contain $2^a\bmod p=g$ rather than $a$, and implement ${(2^a)}^{x+b}\bmod p$ as $g^{x+b}\bmod p$ or $g^{(x+b)\bmod q}\bmod p$. On the other hand, in a black box context, the forward implementation can implement ${(2^a)}^{x+b}\bmod p$ as $2^{(a\,x+b)\bmod q}\bmod p$, which allows a slightly faster evaluation.

The number of iterations of $f_{(p,a,b)}$ is about $p/2^{33}$ on average, and for $p<2^{34}$ is more than $k$ with probability less than about $2^{-k}$. In order to slow down evaluation (and reversal), we can chain several $h_{(p,a,b)}$ using different $p$, which is better that an overlarge $p$ on two accounts: the evaluation time tends to depend less on $x$; and attacks making heavy pre-computations to later efficiently solve multiple discrete logarithm problem in the same $\Bbb Z_p^*$ are thwarted.

---

There seems to be better constructions (in the sense of making the ratio of reverse to forward cost higher) using the DLP on a super-singular elliptic curve; see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12182/555) and its comments, and perhaps [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/312/555) for the curve.

Comment: While I did know that the discrete logarithm is cyclic, I did not know you can choose the parameters to create a permutation in $[1, q]$. Also respect for coming up with the $\tilde f$ function, which basicly allows to reduce any permutation to a $[1,2^{32}]$ permutation.